# jQuery build ul - li navigation based on JSON

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to build a dynamic menu using `ul` and `li` tags. The menu has to be built using the following JSON which I get from the web server. Any ideas how I can implement a menu like this using jQuery based on this structure?

```
var data = [
  {
    "MenuId": "4fde524c-9f8e-4fc4-a7c1-aea177090299",
    "ParentMenuId": null,
    "Title": "Home",
    "Icon": "fa fa-home",
    "DisplayOrder": 10,
    "MenuAction": "/Home/Index",
    "Menus": []
  },
  {
    "MenuId": "172f657e-6bbd-4cca-9ed6-a372dba3c9dc",
    "ParentMenuId": null,
    "Title": "Maintenance",
    "Icon": "fa fa-home",
    "DisplayOrder": 20,
    "MenuAction": "Maintenance",
    "Menus": [
      {
        "MenuId": "f7661f0c-7b0c-4967-bd68-6f39387d7cb8",
        "ParentMenuId": "172f657e-6bbd-4cca-9ed6-a372dba3c9dc",
        "Title": "Users",
        "Icon": "fa fa-home",
        "DisplayOrder": 10,
        "MenuAction": "/Maintenance/Users",
        "Menus": []
      },
      {
        "MenuId": "90130291-db76-4c46-8180-73c5a4056eae",
        "ParentMenuId": "172f657e-6bbd-4cca-9ed6-a372dba3c9dc",
        "Title": "Roles",
        "Icon": "fa fa-home",
        "DisplayOrder": 20,
        "MenuAction": "/Maintenance/Roles",
        "Menus": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MenuId": "867eee51-7702-45b4-9427-ea3bedec4c3e",
    "ParentMenuId": null,
    "Title": "Reports",
    "Icon": "fa fa-home",
    "DisplayOrder": 30,
    "MenuAction": "Reports",
    "Menus": [
      {
        "MenuId": "2905febe-e310-4bc8-abe1-6ec00093458e",
        "ParentMenuId": "867eee51-7702-45b4-9427-ea3bedec4c3e",
        "Title": "Report 1",
        "Icon": "fa fa-home",
        "DisplayOrder": 10,
        "MenuAction": "/Reports/Report1",
        "Menus": []
      },
      {
        "MenuId": "66d9d009-6e1f-4c2b-bf53-fba23bf5e133",
        "ParentMenuId": "867eee51-7702-45b4-9427-ea3bedec4c3e",
        "Title": "Report 2",
        "Icon": "fa fa-home",
        "DisplayOrder": 20,
        "MenuAction": "/Reports/Report2",
        "Menus": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MenuId": "5d3b2b07-8db8-44f4-97b4-30da0bb3cb88",
    "ParentMenuId": null,
    "Title": "Lookup",
    "Icon": "fa fa-home",
    "DisplayOrder": 40,
    "MenuAction": "Lookup",
    "Menus": [
      {
        "MenuId": "dba0985c-2cdb-4302-a405-fdd883c6b37a",
        "ParentMenuId": "5d3b2b07-8db8-44f4-97b4-30da0bb3cb88",
        "Title": "Logs",
        "Icon": "fa fa-home",
        "DisplayOrder": 10,
        "MenuAction": "/Lookup/Logs",
        "Menus": []
      },
      {
        "MenuId": "72344388-6e53-4626-93af-2f74c563f734",
        "ParentMenuId": "5d3b2b07-8db8-44f4-97b4-30da0bb3cb88",
        "Title": "Resources",
        "Icon": "fa fa-home",
        "DisplayOrder": 20,
        "MenuAction": "/Lookup/Resources",
        "Menus": []
      },
      {
        "MenuId": "e4dd9b30-b968-4a80-9284-1ca1c89e2eb0",
        "ParentMenuId": "5d3b2b07-8db8-44f4-97b4-30da0bb3cb88",
        "Title": "Lookup Tables",
        "Icon": "fa fa-home",
        "DisplayOrder": 30,
        "MenuAction": "/Lookup/LookupTables",
        "Menus": []
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4wgaovq/10/

Comment: please post your jquery code too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z4wgaovq/10/

Comment: Based on the above json, how do you want your final output to look like?

Comment: Well I don't need to implement all properties but to build the hierarchy. like parent-child (other classes and id I don't need it) I mean I will manage it, with classes and so forth. I just have some issues in parsing it and building the hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
$.each(data, function(i) {
  //console.log(i);
  item = data[i].Title;
  console.log(item);
  if (data[i].Menus.length) {
    $('#menu').append('<li class="has-sub" id="' + data[i].MenuId + '">' + item + '</li>');
    $('#' + data[i].MenuId).append('<ul></ul>');
    sub_item = data[i].Menus;
    for (j = 0; j < data[i].Menus.length; j++) {
      console.log(j);

      $('#' + data[i].MenuId + ' ul').append('<li>' + sub_item[j].Title + '</li>');

    }
  } else {
    $('#menu').append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
  }

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8mmy1aqu/ You can clean it up a little (i've defined some vars , but didn't used it, and used it later (sub_item) in hurry... :))

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

- You are rendering `<li>`s inside a `<div>`
- Your `<div>` has id `#menu` and **must** be `menu`
- You should wrap it all inside a `$(document).ready();`
- You are using `$.append()` on empty elements. Avoid this when possible.

Doing so will solve the issue.

Also, using `items[items.length]='html'` instead of `items.push()` will speed up your code.

Also, notice that the code you have isn't JSON: that is a regular Javascript object.

Comment: I did fixed that :) My mistake please check the JSFiddle url I added (made some changes)

Comment: @DavidDury I will check it now.

Comment: @DavidDury JSON is a string representing a tree-structure of data. What you have there is a Javascript object.